# CoffeeScript: why won't my class work without prefixing with window?

Tags: coffeescript

I have an external file where I have defined my class:

```
class MyClass
  constructor: ->
    alert 'hello'
```

When the CoffeeScript is compiled into JavaScript, it wraps it with a closure. So when I try to use it in some JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  var ob = new MyClass();
});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined
```

but if I prefix the class name with window, it will work:

```
class window.MyClass
  constructor: ->
    alert 'hello'
```

How can I define my class without prefixing with window?

Comment: I often do `self.MyClass = class MyClass` and had wondered if there is a better way.  Incidentally, I use `self` because it's more portable, web workers don't have a `window` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the CoffeeScript with the `--bare` but that's generally not recommended because you may pollute the global namespace.

My suggestion is to attach the class to the `window` object, like your second example, or even better, use this namespace function from the CoffeeScript docs to attach your classes to a single global object attached to the `window`

```
namespace = (target, name, block) ->
  [target, name, block] = [(if typeof exports isnt 'undefined' then exports else window), arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
  top    = target
  target = target[item] or= {} for item in name.split '.'
  block target, top

# Usage:
#
namespace 'Hello.World', (exports) ->
  # `exports` is where you attach namespace members
  exports.hi = -> console.log 'Hi World!'

namespace 'Say.Hello', (exports, top) ->
  # `top` is a reference to the main namespace
  exports.fn = -> top.Hello.World.hi()

Say.Hello.fn()  # prints 'Hi World!'
```

Source: [CoffeeScript FAQ](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ)